# Probability on biased dice

Tags: probability, dice

Two dice are biased, so that the probability of getting a 6 on each dice equals 0.3. The two dice are rolled, and by using a tree diagram or otherwise, I would like to find:

1. P(two 6's)
2. P(exactly one 6)

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The probability of getting two 6's equals $0.3 \cdot 0.3 = 0.09$
2. The probability of getting one 6 equals $0.3 \cdot 0.7 + 0.7 \cdot 0.3 = 0.42$

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hiaq.png]

Comment: You are very welcome. Please consider upvoting/accepting the answer, if you think it could be of interest to others.

Comment: I have reputation score less than 15 . I am unable to upvote . But thanks for help . Once I reach 15 I'll do it